# How to design multiple ways to invoke REST API

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using ASP.NET Web API. I want to REST uri to be

`GET /api/v1/documents/1234/download` or

`GET /api/v1/documents/1234?act=download` or

`GET /api/v1/documents?id=1234&act=download`

Is it possible to have multiple ways to call REST API Url? Is it recommended?

I am using `Attribute Routes` only

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1")]
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    private readonly DomainService _domainService;

    public DocumentController(DomainService domainService)
        : base(domainService)
    {
        _domainService = domainService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(domainService));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("documents/{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DownloadDocument([FromUri]int id, [FromUri]string act)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(act) || act.ToUpper() != "DOWNLOAD")
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid action parameter.");
        }

        return await service.DownloadFile(id);
    }
}
```

with above code only `GET /api/v1/documents/1234?act=download` works. Is it possible to configure route in a such way that all 3 routes will invoke same action method?

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many `Route` attributes as required to each method.
So you could do this to your method:

```
[Route("documents")]                 // matches /documents?id=123&act=download
[Route("documents/{id:int}")]        // matches /documents/123?act=download
[Route("documents/{id:int}/{act}")]  // matches /documents/123/download
```

Personally I think this is quite long-winded, and would try to stick to a single style (the last one if I could choose), but I guess it could depend on your requirements.